# ASP.NET Write out contents of HTML file?

Tags: asp.net, html, response.write

I don't know if this is a stupid question but..

Is it possible in either ASP.NET (either C# or VB#) to Response.Write() the contents of another HTML file? If so, how?

Comment: Inline in the current file or instead of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the HTML file line by line and write it using Response.Write()

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\abc.html");
        while(sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
           line=sr.ReadLine();
           Response.Write(line);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the lines into a string array and send them out directly.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path/to/my/file.html");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Response.Write(line);
}
```

Just don't forget to set your headers up correctly because this will just inject HTML. It won't set up any special headers that might be expected (if any).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I have another solution for future researching. How about just use TrasmitFile? i.e.:

```
Response.WriteFile(@"folder/filename.html");
```