# .NET Custom Middleware to display a webpage/form

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, middleware

I am trying to figure out how I can create my own middleware, to provide a Form or Webpage.

It should be usable like HangFire or NSwager and it should work for .NET Core WebApp and WebApi projects:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseSwaggerUi3();
```

So in my case i would like to use it like:

```
app.UseMyDashboard();
```

What it needs to do:

1. Provide an endpoint (/myDashboard)
2. This page contains a simple form
3. Submit the form and execute some code

How do I do something like that ? Do I need to create a separate project for this? Because I want to reuse this in any other projects, meaning I want to pack this in a NuGet package and make it available for internal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide you a brief answer to start with, you can go through the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for detais. To call `app.UseMyDashboard();` from startup class you would need to create an extension method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class MiddleWareExtension
    {
        public static void UseMyDashboard(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            // 1. Provide an endpoint(/ myDashboard)
            app.Map("/myDashboard", app =>
                app.Run(async (context) =>
                {
                    //2. This page contains a simple form, Submit the form to redirect to another form
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("<button onclick=\"window.location.href = '/path'; \">Click me</button>");
                }));
            //3. Another Form
            app.Map("/path", app =>
                app.Run(async (context) => await context.Response.WriteAsync("<b>New Form</b>")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible to have the HTML in a file and a separate project ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509417/asp-net-write-out-contents-of-html-file